# Can't access properties of an object

Tags: reactjs

[image]I can't access the keys of the object that I pass through props to my EditField component. When I log the prop I passed into the console it outputs the object correctly, but when I try to get any key of that object I get an "undefined error". What's up with that object? On the picture is the object I get when doing console.log(department) Look at my code:

```
class EditForm extends React.Component {
render() {
const departments = this.props.departments
const showcasedDepName = this.props.showcasedDepName
const dep = departments.filter(dep => dep.depName === 
showcasedDepName)[0]
return(
      ...irrelevant stuff
      <EditField department={dep}/>
    </form>
  </div>
)
}
}
```

EditField component:

```
class EditField extends React.Component {
render() {
const department = this.props.department
console.log(department.depName) //"undefined", whereas it shows me the correct object when I do console.log(department)
return(
  <div className="edit-dep">
    <div>Department name: <input type="text" value=
{department.depName}/></div>
  </div>
)
}
}
```

Comment: Could you add the structure of the object? Or what comes in console.log(department)

Comment: added to the post

Comment: Try console.log(department[0].depName)

Comment: Doesn't work. It's an object since I put [0] at the end of 'dep' constant in render method of EditForm component.

Comment: When changing console.log(department), which outputs an object,  to console.log(Object.keys(department)) i get "Cannot convert undefined or null to object". Pretty weird.

Comment: Try `const { department } = this.props.department
console.log(department.depName)`

Comment: Doesn't work. I get "Cannot match against 'undefined' or 'null' "

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it! The problem came from where I didn't expect it to come. I counted the amount of workers in componentDidMount function where I changed the state of 'depAmount' key from null to the length of the array of workers. When I replaced componentDidMount with componentWillMount the problem dissappeared. I guess the reason why I had this error is that the state initially rendered with null value.